# How development remote project using Pycharm without cloning the file to local environment?

Tags: pycharm

I have a big project located on a remote server. Now I just want to open these files and code it (maybe debug and run the project) without cloning the file to my local pc.

The procedure that Pycharm configures a project is too slow. Meanwhile, some data files are too big(TB size), impossible to clone it to local pc. I know that I can exclude it through configuring the **development** tool. But it's not the experience I desire.

I just want a simple editor to do some code and run it. Just like using vim to edit and `python xxx.py` with ssh on iterm2, but with a good debugging experience.

Comment: [Here is the corresponding feature request for PyCharm](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-19752). You could leave a vote there.

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially try mounting the folder your project lives in over SSH using [SSHFS](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/SSHFS). It's unconventional but it would allow you to open up your project in pycharm.

Speed of it would depend on your internet connection, latency, etc.

Another way would be to install something like [VSCode Server](https://github.com/cdr/code-server) on the actual host. This will allow you to open up VSCode instance in your browser.

Comment: Mounting would be the same as download the project, using ssh doesn't satisfy his debugging request

Comment: @lssilva sshfs does not copy any files over the network when you mount a remote directory. It does not even copy files when you `cd` into a sshfs-mounted directory. When you `cd` into a directory, sshfs fetches the names of the files.

The actual contents of files only get transferred by when you access a file.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to edit your remote code repository through VSCode 1.56 (Apr. 2021) [VSCode "Remote Repository" feature](https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_56#_remote-repositories-remotehub)

> ### Remote Repositories (RemoteHub)#
>
> As part of this release, we are previewing a new built-in extension, Remote Repositories (RemoteHub), which allows you to instantly browse, search, edit, and commit to any GitHub repository directly from within VS Code without having to clone or have the repository locally.
>
> To get started, run the Open Remote Repository... command from the Command Palette. From there, you can paste in any GitHub URL, or choose to search for a specific repository or pull request.
>
> [image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_56/open-remote-repository.png]
>
> Once you enter a URL or choose a repository or pull request, VS Code will open a new workspace for that repository.
> The remote status indicator, on the left side of the Status bar, shows the connected remote provider name, for example GitHub, for the remote repository.
>
> [image: https://code.visualstudio.com/assets/updates/1_56/remote-repositories.gif]

Now:

- it seems to be limited to GitHub repositories
- it has limited language intelligence - Many language servers don't yet understand this virtualized environment. TypeScript supports single file intelligence for remote repositories.
- and limited extension support - As with language servers, many extensions don't work with remote repositories. Extensions can opt-out and will not be activated for virtual workspaces.

It will be however [publicly available in VSCode 1.57 (May 2021)](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-docs/blob/6651e6b0dee916c8f7ead3da7baf0f6f18c969ee/release-notes/v1_57.md#remote-repositories), with a  few new features.

> You can now see your remote repositories in the Remote Explorer view, to quickly open or see and compare any uncommitted changes you may have.
>
> Additionally, you can apply changes, from the same repository, to the current remote repository — allowing you to quickly and easily move uncommitted changes from one branch to another.

Answer (score -1):

You can check remote interpreter using Docker:

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/using-docker-as-a-remote-interpreter.html

Without docker might be harder

Comment: Well, I am not the administrator of this server. And sadly docker is not installed on this server.